# OpenCV 2.4.6 cannot find CUDA on Win8

Tags: opencv

System config:
Win8 64-bit
VS 2010 64-bit
CUDA 5.5 64-bit
OpenCV 2.4.6 (using 64-bit libs and dlls)

I am trying to use CUDA enabled libraries for OpenCV. I installed CUDA 5.5 and OpenCV 2.4.6. From various forums, I gathered that OpenCV 2.4.6 does not have a separate /gpu directory under /build, and I should be using the libs and dlls under the /build/x64/vc10 directory. When making GPU calls, I get the error message that "The library is compiled without CUDA support".

I tried building OpenCV from source keeping the WITH_CUDA flag checked. After a few attempts, the build succeeded but I did not find the opencv_gpu300d.lib in the output directory. Without linking this file, I get unresolved externals when building the test example.

I have ensured that CUDA works correctly by writing a small kernel and testing it. My PATH environment variable has the following CUDA entries:
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\libnvvp;

I need to run CUDA enabled functions of OpenCV. How can I do this without having to build OpenCV again by myself?

Comment: Check all CMake variables for CUDA_ like CUDATOOLKITROOTDIRCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR, CUDATOOLKITINCLUDECUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE, etc in cmake-gui or in CMakeCache.txt.

Comment: If you are building OpenCV 2.4.6, why are you trying to link `opencv_gpu300d.lib`? Link `opencv_gpu246d.lib` instead.